# How to tell where the application is being ran in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, wget

I'm using wget along side my app to download a jar and run it. Problem is with my current setup wget.exe would have to be kept in a folder in the app data and that really isn't smart i.e. how would the file get there to begin with?

So how would one find the directory the app is being run in no matter where it is being ran from?

Comment: And you app has started up `wget`?

Comment: Started up? No?
I've been using system() calls to use it

Comment: A `system()` call starts up the other program, yes. That's how it works. `wget` can't do anything unless `wget` is running. The purpose of `system()` is to cause another program to run.

Comment: @Thunder - Are you asking for the directory containing the executable? Generally you are not allowed to install any files there.

Answer (score 3):

for windows:

```
std::string calculateRunPath()
{
  const unsigned int size = 500;
  char buf[size] = {0};
  HMODULE hModule = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
  GetModuleFileName(hModule,buf, sizeof(buf));

  std::string path(buf);
  size_t pos = path.find_last_of('\\');

  return path.substr(0, pos);
}
```

for Linux:

```
std::string calculateRunPath()
{
   const unsigned int size = 500;
   char path[size + 1] = {0};  

   size_t len = readlink("/proc/self/exe", path, size);
   path[len]   = 0;
   char* p = strrchr(path, '/');
   if(p) 
      *(p + 1) = 0;
   else 
      path[0] = 0;

   return std::string(path);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some boost filesystem goodness should work too, something like...

```
#include <boost/filesystem/path.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem/operations.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << boost::filesystem::current_path().string() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This would be portable too across different operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

You have to read the PWD environment variable

Comment: When I tired
    std::cout << getenv("PATH") It spat out about 10 paths.

Comment: PATH is not the current position, is the list of directories to search into when you run a command. I.e. when you write "cd" system looks in those paths to find the cd command. you can use that var if you want be able to put wget.exe where you want.